# Cannot load files inside the public folder - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, laravel, apache, laravel-5.4

I got a problem while working with Laravel 5.4. I do need to load some pics which are under the public folder `public/img`. In order to do so, I tried the following lines of code in my blade view:

1. `<img src="{{Config::get('app.url')}}/public/img/boy.png" width="30"/>`
2. `<img src="{{url('/img/boy.png')}}" />`

In both of the cases, I get this URL which looks (apparently) ok: `http://localhost/public/img/boy.png`. My application is running fine on this URL: `http://localhost:8000/`.

The problem is that pic (as well as others in the same folder), cannot be loaded. On the HTML page, I get the following error in the console: `http://localhost/public/img/boy.png 404 (Not Found)`.

How can it be possible? Actually, if I try to go to `http://localhost/public/img/boy.png`, I get an error that the page does not exist.

How can this problem be solved? How can I get access to my files in the public folder? I have been spending the whole day trying to figure this issue out!

Thank you so much!

Comment: set url to .env file (default is `http://localhost`), use `asset()` for linking public files.

Comment: I have also tried this solution - no results :(

Answer (score 2):

add following to your routes and try. I use storage folder instead of public path.

```
Route::get('/images/{filename}', function ($filename, Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $path = public_path() . "/img/$filename";
    // $path = storage_path() . "/images/$filename"; //i normally use this, as i put it in storage folder

    //add validations if you want

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

so now when you go to `http://localhost/images/boy.png` you will get  `/public/img/boy.png`

Comment: How would I do this with txt, css and js files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **asset** It will generate url to png file.

```
{{ asset('img/boy.png') }}
```

**Update**

As suggested in  [this post](https://daveismyname.blog/laravel-55-change-public-to-public-html) you can change **public_path()**

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() { return __DIR__; });
```

Adjust **__DIR__** according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I have already tried to use it as well ... but it does not work either :(

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: can your directly access your file http://localhost/public/img/boy.png , because 404 error indicate that file does not exists.

Comment: No, I cannot directly access my file localhost/public/img/boy.png either - but I have my file under `/public/img/boy.png` . Do not really know how I can get it and what's wrong in my code :(

Comment: @Joe recheck the name of your file file specially uppercase/lowercase characters. *boy.png* and *Boy.png* are not same.

Comment: I know. I double checked several times - _boy.png_ is the right name

Comment: I am running the server in this way. Dunno if this can be the problem: `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public -f serve.php`

Comment: Check the output of  *public_path()* Route::get('testpath', function () { return public_path(); });

Comment: Thanks! You are right! The _public_path()_ is something like this: `.../myprojectname/public` . I can actually see the pic at this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/boy.png` ... need to figure out how to omit the "public" part when I want to load an image now

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your app is running or http://localhost:8000/ so your image should be this url http://localhost:8000/public/img/boy.png.
That makes sense I think. You are running your app on port 8000 so you should specify the port for all your assests

Comment: The image is at this URL: `http://localhost:8000/img/boy.png` - without _public_ . Just checked it :)